Is there a way to install libffi files manually? (toolchain build kivy does not work)
I'm trying to package my Kivy app for iOS following this
When I need to use toolchain build kivy, I get all kinds of different errors. Now I am stuck on building libffi.
I have gotten all kinds of errors when trying to use toolchain build kivy. Now I am stuck on it not being able to build libffi:
[INFO    ] Build_all libffi
[INFO    ] Build libffi for iphoneos-arm64, iphonesimulator-arm64 (filtered)
[DEBUG   ] Cached result: Build libffi. Ignoring
[INFO    ] Build libffi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/bin/toolchain", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ~~~~^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 1669, in main
    ToolchainCL()
    ~~~~~~~~~~~^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 1406, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.command)()
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 1482, in build
    build_recipes(args.recipe, ctx)
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 1230, in build_recipes
    recipe.execute()
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 757, in execute
    self.build_all()
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 77, in _cache_execution
    f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    ~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 857, in build_all
    self.build(plat)
    ~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 77, in _cache_execution
    f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    ~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 837, in build
    self.set_marker("building")
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 639, in set_marker
    with open(join(self.build_dir, ".{}".format(marker)), "w") as fd:
         ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/akukaukinen/build/libffi/iphonesimulator-arm64/libffi-3.4.4/.building'

It seems like some file is missing. Can I download it some else way?
